# Find when two teams will meet in a bracket using Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm looking for a method to tell at what **ROUND** and **MATCH** (position in round) two teams will meet in a standard sports bracket.

Assuming 16 teams are in the bracket, in numerical order.
I'd like to quickly enter the two team numbers and get the answer.

Here are some examples of when teams would meet:

**Teams 1 vs Team 16 (Can only meet in final)**

ROUND 4 - MATCH 1

**Team 11 vs Team 15 (Would meet in semis)**

ROUND 3 - MATCH 2

**Team 3 vs Team 4 (Would meet in the first round)**

ROUND 1 - MATCH 2

I'm sure I could do this with loops, but I've got a feeling there's going to be a maths based solution, which would be cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wrote this, which seems to work, but feels clunky.
- will link to a jsfiddle as code highlighting isn't working for me!

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bxsx4c4v/3/

The one thing I did was change the team numbers so they could be in an array (for example, team 1 is 0 - team 16 is 15).

Comment: @Richard starting the team numbers from zero *does* make the math a _lot_ easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't (AFAIK) be done with any single maths formula.

If you take the team numbers as starting from 0 rather than 1, then two teams can only meet in the final if the 3rd binary bit of their team numbers are different:

```
if ((teamA ^ teamB) & 8 != 0) {
    // meet in final
    round = 4;
    match = 1;
}
```

If there's a chance they might meet in the semi-final instead, then that can only happen if the 2nd binary bit of their team numbers are different, *and* they weren't caught in the previous test:

```
else if ((teamA ^ teamB) & 4 != 0) {
    // meet in semi-final
    round = 3;
    match = Math.floor(teamA / 8) + 1;
}
```

& so on...

A simple loop would actually do this quite nicely:

```
for (var round = 4; round > 0; --round) {
    if ((teamA ^ teamB) & (1 << (round - 1))) {
        match = (teamA >> round) + 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help; I'm looking at your loop, it seems to make sense!
I'll let you know!

Comment: @Richard I've revised the loop version slightly to simplify it